# SQL Partitioning, how to select a record in the partitioned group that meets certain criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a query. This query is:

```
select Q1.* from (
    select
        a.CreatedDate as KynectCreatedDate,
        a.FirstName,
        b.CaseStatusCode,
        a.Id as ContactId,
        a.Email as EmailAddress,
        a.MobilePhone,
        row_number() over (partition by a.Email order by b.CaseStatusCode desc) as row
    from
        ent.Contact_Salesforce a
    left join
        ent.SOMETABLE_Contact_Shared c on a.Email = c.Email
    left join
        ent.SOMETABLE_Case_Shared b on c.IndividualId = b.IndividualId and c.CaseNumber = b.CaseNumber
    where a.Email = 'aaa@aaa.com') Q1
where Q1.row = 1
```

Here's what I want.  The group of records that come back as defined in the partition by clause - say there's 3 that come back (row number 1, 2, 3).  If CaseStatusCode is "AC" on any of them, PICK THAT RECORD OUT OF THE GROUP.  Otherwise, DOESN'T MATTER WHAT RECORD I PICK.  Right now, the query is just picking the first record in the group (`where Q1.row = 1`).  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put that information in the `order by`:

```
    row_number() over (partition by a.Email order by (case when b.CaseStatusCode 'AC' then 1 else 2 end) as row
```